# Change account in Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I inadvertently created a new Ubuntu One account for myself when I got a new laptop. (I have 2 email addresses, and the one I input was not the one on which I had already created my Ubuntu One account.) Now that I have set up Ubuntu One incorrectly on this computer, there does not seem to be any way to rectify the situation. I have tried removing and reinstalling Ubuntu One according to the instructions at https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+faq/778. When I start up the Ubuntu One client after reinstalling, it asks for authentication, and then says "Ubuntu One is installing ..." basically forever. If I quit the Ubuntu One client and try starting it again, the same thing happens. Using 11.10 on a Lenovo laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Quit the Ubuntu One client and use these commands in a terminal to reset the configuration files for your user

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.share/local/ubuntuone
rm -rf ~/.cache/ubuntuone
rm -rf ~/.config/ubuntuone
mv ~/Ubuntu\ One/ ~/Ubuntu\ One_old/
```

Look for `Passwords and Encryption Keys` on your dash, go to the Passwords tab, delete the Ubuntu One token.
Note: if you do not have Unity/Gnome installed you will need to install the Password and Encrytpion Keys program.

```
sudo apt-get install seahorse
```

to remove all the UbuntuOne program files and reinstall run:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone*
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone*
```

Open Ubuntu One again and you will have all UbuntuOne reseted and ready to be used with any account you provide. Old files under the previous setup will be in your `~/Ubuntu One_old` folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Search for and launch the "Password and Keys" application.
2. On Password and Keys application Right-click on Ubuntu One in the list.
3. Select Delete from the context menu that pops up.
4. Start Ubuntu One from the Unity Launcher on the left.
5. You will be allowed to enter the user id and password that you would like to use.
6. You should then have the option add your computer to this Ubuntu One account.